# Android Volley traffic stats

Tags: android, networking, statistics, android-volley, traffic

I'm playing with the Android Volley library and I need to find a way to measure the amount of bytes involved in any JsonObjectRequest queued in a RequestQueue object.
I need just to measure the overall amount of bytes for each request, included http and lower levels overhead.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Do you wish to get the data inside your app for later use? Or is this for debugging purpose?

1) If it is for analytics for users, then I think you can use trafficStats.
2) If it is for debugging purpose, I would suggest using a monitoring tool like CharlesProxy which will help you monitor and get the data you require.